# Using the value in a cell to define range in a formula?

Tags: excel, range, google-sheets

In spreadsheet I'd like to use MAX to return the highest value in a range.  The range needs to be defined by the value in another column. So lets say the table has three columns: Animal|Type|Length, with each animal listed designated as Type: Mammal, Bird, or Fish, along with that animal's length in feet. So a row might say:

Dog | Mammal | 2

So, in plain English I'm looking for a formula that would ask "Which is the greatest length of all the animals designated as 'Mammal' in this table?" Same for the other Types, so that I would have a table like this, with a formula populating the Max Length cells:

**Type** | **Max Length**

Mammal | 6

Bird | 5

Fish | 6

Thanks - any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've revised my answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/55465/29140. If your using Google Spreadsheets, then Web Applications is the place to be !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an "array formula" here, e.g. if your three columns are A (`Animal`), B (`Type`) and C (`Length`) you can use a formula like this in F2

`=MAX(IF(B$2:B$100=E2,C$2:C$100))`

where `E2` contains the type

confirm formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down

Comment: Oh! I didn't see the "google-spreadsheet" tag - you can also use `FILTER` function in Google, i.e. `=max(filter(C$2:C$100,B$2:B$100=E2))`

Comment: Thanks Barry - =max(filter(C$2:C$100,B$2:B$100=E2)) is exactly what I needed.